# Avoiding Deadlocks when deleting relationships

Tags: neo4j, deadlock

I am using embedded neo4j as a Web Service. Part of my model is like so:

```
(user)-[HAS_ITEM]->(item)
```

Now I have several deletes coming in at one time for different `users`, but for some of the same `items`. I know I will get deadlocks if I do these updates as Neo4j will lock the node when I try to delete. The recommended strategy I've seen has been to order these updates, so I do, I take the list of `item` nodes I need to remove and order them, so I'm always removing in some predictable order. However when I delete the relationships, I get another problem related to the relationships locking, even though they are different relationships. Here is the error:

```
Details: 'Transaction(43141)[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=1] can't wait on resource RWLock[Relationship[620613598]] since => Transaction(43141)[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=1] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[Node[620]] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- Transaction(43142)[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=0] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[Relationship[620613598]]'.

Details: 'Transaction(43746)[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=0] can't wait on resource RWLock[Node[620]] since => Transaction(43746)[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=0] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[Lockable relationship #620634878] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- Transaction(43747)[STATUS_ACTIVE,Resources=1] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[Node[620]]'.
```

How can I remove this issue? I believed that the node was the only point of contention here, however there seems to be a lock on the relationship that the transactions are fighting for, even though each transaction shouldn't be handling the delete of these relationships(the remove is mutually exclusive to the `user`).

Comment: You can try to acquire a write lock, calling *acquireWriteLock* method on both user and item nodes before removing the relationship.

Comment: Yes. But for my update, each transaction is for 1 `user`, so I know that isn't in contention. I know the `items` can be the same, however I'm accessing them in a predictable pattern, so even if I am locking on it, it shouldn't be a deadlock on that node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Neo4j` locks the relationship, as well as 4 other relationships attached in the linked list that is stored on the disk. That is why I get the message I do. The solution here is to either retry the deadlocked delete, or to put locks around both nodes explicitly.